# using numpy to reduce the size of the matrix

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I have to create an adjacency list of users and TV shows where the rows are the users and the TV shows are the columns. If a user follows that TV show then there will be a 1 in the matrix else a zero. This information I have already collected from twitter. In total there are 140 TV shows and approximately 530000 unique users. I am using the following code to generate the matrix, using python:

- NoTvShows: Total number of TV shows(IDs)
- unique_user: All the unique users
- collected_users: This is a list of lists. The sublists correspond to TV shows and list the IDs of the followers.

```
for i in range(0,NoTvShows):
    for every_user in unique_users:
        if every_user in collected_users[i]:
            matrix.append(1)
        else:
            matrix.append(0)
    main_matrix.append(matrix)
    matrix = []

the_matrix = zip(*main_matrix)
simplejson.dump(the_matrix,fwrite)
fwrite.close()
```

When I try executing my program on the server, it crashes as it is taking a lot of time and memory. I know I can use numpy to reduce the size of my matrix and then use it to compute similarities between the users. However, I am not sure as to how to code the numpy in this code and generate the reduced matrix.

I hope someone can guide me in this regard

Thank you

Richa

Answer (score 6):

Sparse matrices (as [suggested by @phg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10345687/344821)) are good, since most of the entries in your matrix are probably 0 (assuming most users follow only a few TV shows).

Probably more importantly, though, you're building the matrix in a very inefficient way (making lots of lists of python lists and copying them around), rather than just putting them in a nice compact numpy array in the first place. Also, you're spending a ton of time searching through lists (with the `in` statement), when that's just not at all necessary for your loops.

This code loops over the follower list and looks up the user # for each id in a `user_ids` dictionary. You can adapt it to a sparse matrix class pretty trivially (just switch `np.zeros` to `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`, I think).

```
user_ids = dict((user, i) for i, user in enumerate(unique_users))

follower_matrix = np.zeros(NoTvShows, len(unique_users), dtype=bool)
for show_idx, followers in enumerate(collected_users):
    for user in followers:
        follower_matrix[show_idx, user_ids[user]] = 1
```

Once you have the matrix, you really, really don't want to save it as JSON unless you have to: it's a really wasteful format for numeric matrices. [`numpy.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) is best if you're only using the data matrix again in numpy. `numpy.savetxt` also works and at least eliminates the brackets and commas, and will probably have less memory overhead while writing. But when you have a 0-1 matrix and it's in the boolean datatype, `numpy.save` only needs one bit per matrix element, while `numpy.savetxt` needs two bytes = 16 bits (an ascii `'0'` or `'1'` plus a space or newline), and json uses at least three bytes, I think (comma, space, plus some brackets on each line).

---

You may also be talking about dimensionality reduction techniques. That's also very possible; there are lots of techniques out there to reduce your vector of 140 dimensions (which TV shows are followed) to lower dimensionality, either by some kind of PCA-type technique, a topic model, maybe something based on clustering.... If your only concern is that it's taking a long time to build the matrix, though, that's not going to help at all (since those techniques generally require the full original matrix and then give you a lower-dimensional version). Try my suggestions here, if it's not good enough try a sparse matrix, and then worry about fancy ways to reduce the data (probably by learning a dimensionality reduction on a subset of the data and then constructing the rest).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use a [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) for reducing space. I found this for scipy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

I hope that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach in case you're interested. It assumes your users are in stored order, but they can be numeric or string ids:

```
# The setup
users = ['bob', 'dave', 'steve']
users = np.array(users)
collected_users = [['bob'], ['dave'], ['steve', 'dave'], ['bob', 'steve', 'dave']]
NoTvShows = len(collected_users)

# The meat
matrix = np.zeros((NoTvShows, len(users)), 'bool')
for i, watches in enumerate(collected_users):
    index = users.searchsorted(watches)
    matrix[i, index] = 1
```

Comment: This is exactly how I have data stored. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know `searchsorted` worked with multiple values at once - pretty handy. With 530k users, though, I think a dictionary will still probably win. (I was curious, so I [dug into the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L1498), and it's just doing independent binary search for each one, nothing fancy. This way does put those loops into C, but 530,000 is still pretty big.)

Comment: Ya, I didn't time it to see which would be faster. Dictionaries are amazing, I just wanted to give a more numpy-ie approach. I guess the question becomes is the python for-loop overhead more than log(530,000).

Comment: I was curious, so I tested this out. Using a 530,000-long array of random length strings, `searchsorted` beats a python loop looking things up in a dictionary for every case I tried -- though both approaches take on the order of 3 to 50 microseconds, depending on the length of the strings involved and how many things you're searching for. Of course, log_2(530,000) is only 20.